# How do I get Windows 10 to "resetup" my user?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

How can I trick Windows 10 into first time setup so I can reset all the settings for my user account? I'm using Windows 10 1903. Specifically, how do I delete all my settings for my user, so when I login Windows will recreate those files, but keep my files?

Comment: I do not think you can. You need to back up the user information and then from another admin user, delete this user, restart and set it up again. Then restore your data. That makes it new again

Comment: You can reset your the settings within the Settings application

Comment: *reset all the settings*... Can you be more explicit about what outcome you want? For example, do you want to start over with a new user profile? Or just reset settings but not lose documents?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes, but not really. I don't want my user to be deleted, I just want to trick Windows into thinking I have logged on to my user for the first time.

Comment: The definition of logging into an account for the first time would be the *absence of all settings* (i.e. the files that store settings don't exist). How do you imagine this to look differently than saving your documents then deleting your user profile?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Sorry, I meant how do I delete my user profile (recreate it), keeping all my documents, but remove all my settings? It's hard for me to explain through one comment.

Comment: Your profile consists of 1. Settings and 2. Documents. There is **no difference** between saving your documents, deleting your profile, then restoring your documents versus the process you're asking for to delete only your settings. Given this, can you explain why  you wish to avoid this approach? Is there something you're afraid of losing?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The last time I tried recreating my user, my User folder was named something different.